# Understanding onMeasure implementation in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewgroup, onmeasure

I was going through the code of ViewPager for some unrelated reason and I saw that it overrides onMeasure of ViewGroup. I've been trying to learn how to properly implement onMeasure so I decided to take a closer look. Here's the method for reference-

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // For simple implementation, our internal size is always 0.
    // We depend on the container to specify the layout size of
    // our view.  We can't really know what it is since we will be
    // adding and removing different arbitrary views and do not
    // want the layout to change as this happens.
    setMeasuredDimension(getDefaultSize(0, widthMeasureSpec),
            getDefaultSize(0, heightMeasureSpec));

    final int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    final int maxGutterSize = measuredWidth / 10;
    mGutterSize = Math.min(maxGutterSize, mDefaultGutterSize);

    // Children are just made to fill our space.
    int childWidthSize = measuredWidth - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int childHeightSize = getMeasuredHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

    /*
     * Make sure all children have been properly measured. Decor views first.
     * Right now we cheat and make this less complicated by assuming decor
     * views won't intersect. We will pin to edges based on gravity.
     */
    int size = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            if (lp != null && lp.isDecor) {
                final int hgrav = lp.gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
                final int vgrav = lp.gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
                int widthMode = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
                int heightMode = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
                boolean consumeVertical = vgrav == Gravity.TOP || vgrav == Gravity.BOTTOM;
                boolean consumeHorizontal = hgrav == Gravity.LEFT || hgrav == Gravity.RIGHT;

                if (consumeVertical) {
                    widthMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                } else if (consumeHorizontal) {
                    heightMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                }

                int widthSize = childWidthSize;
                int heightSize = childHeightSize;
                if (lp.width != LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
                    widthMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                    if (lp.width != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                        widthSize = lp.width;
                    }
                }
                if (lp.height != LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
                    heightMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                    if (lp.height != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                        heightSize = lp.height;
                    }
                }
                final int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSize, widthMode);
                final int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, heightMode);
                child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                if (consumeVertical) {
                    childHeightSize -= child.getMeasuredHeight();
                } else if (consumeHorizontal) {
                    childWidthSize -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    mChildWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidthSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    mChildHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeightSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    // Make sure we have created all fragments that we need to have shown.
    mInLayout = true;
    populate();
    mInLayout = false;

    // Page views next.
    size = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Measuring #" + i + " " + child + ": " + mChildWidthMeasureSpec);
            }

            final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            if (lp == null || !lp.isDecor) {
                final int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        (int) (childWidthSize * lp.widthFactor), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                child.measure(widthSpec, mChildHeightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand the logic behind handling gravity of Decor views. As far as I understand, if there are two child views- one with gravity top-left and the other with top-right, the code would subtract the height of both the child views from **childHeightSize**. This seems wrong to me because the logic should only subtract the height of the child view that has the maximum height.

Why is it implemented like this?